# I added a map as a field in my Firestore DB document with a sub field inside, and I am facing issues to my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am facing issues with my RecyclerView in displaying my app's candidates when I include the added map field in my query. I also have created an index for this query but still, nothing comes out of my RecyclerView.

This is the UPDATED query code. If there is something wrong with the coding, please do notify me.

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String voterID = user.getUid();
    Query query = notebookRef.whereEqualTo("registrationStatus", "Accepted").whereEqualTo( voterID, false).orderBy("candidateFullName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<VoterCandidateItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<VoterCandidateItem>()
            .setQuery(query, VoterCandidateItem.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new VoterCandidateAdapter(options);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.candidateList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

This is the UPDATED screenshot of Firestore DB:
[image]

And this is the UPDATED screenshot of the index:
[image]

Comment: .....whereEqualTo( voterID, false)...where is voterID? I dont see it

Comment: @SusanMustafa my bad. I will include it in the code above right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query:

```
Query query = notebookRef
        .whereEqualTo("registrationStatus", "Accepted")
        .whereEqualTo(voterID, false)
        .orderBy("candidateFullName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Requires an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing), otherwise, it will **not** work. If you are using Android Studio, you'll find in the logcat an error message that looks like this:

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/...
```

The required query can be created either directly in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/), or by clicking on that link. If the click doesn't work, simply copy and paste the URL into a web browser and your index will be created automatically for you.

If you choose the console, remember to set:

> Collection: **Candidates**
> Fields: **registrationStatus ascending** and **voterID: ascending**

Comment: I already have that index created through the link I saw in logcat but still, my RecyclerView is not displaying my candidates that satisfy the query.

Comment: But the `String voterID` contains the email of the current user. How can I use the email as a field name for `.whereEqualTo`?

Comment: I just tried using the UID as the `voterID` and even added a field of the same name with the UID of the current user, and created an index for it but I am still not seeing anything from my RecyclerView

Comment: Most likely there is another issue with the RecyclerView itself. Have you tried to log the result inside the adapter class to see if you get the right results?

Comment: QUICK UPDATE: I included a `.` operator in the query of the map and then my candidates appeared on the RecyclerView but the logcat is still recommending me to create an index for it. Do I have to if it works now?

Comment: If the message it's still there then that query or another one requires it.

Comment: Thank you for consistently answering my questions! I will post more soon if I come across another problem :)

Comment: Ok, if you'll add a new question, I'll take a look at it ;)

Comment: I have a new problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928802/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-a-sub-field-of-a-map-field-in-a-document-in-firesto

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.