# Alternative ways of using dynamic values in creating composite index for queries in Firestore DB

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a hard time thinking about what static value to put in a query for my online voting application. What I want to happen is that every voter can see list of candidates on their screens but later removed from the list when they already voted the selected candidate. With this concept in mind, I have constructed a query like this:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String voterID = user.getUid();
    Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("posOrder").orderBy("candidateFullName").whereEqualTo("Voters." + voterID, false);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<VoterCandidateItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<VoterCandidateItem>()
            .setQuery(query, VoterCandidateItem.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new VoterCandidateAdapter(options);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.candidateList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Now, using the query, the logcat recommends creating a composite index for this query to make it work, and this is what the Firebase Console showed me:

[image]

The problem in creating this composite index is that it will only display the list for the current user who has the UID of **TNn7J...J33**, and this is not allowed in creating a working composite index.

Here is the screenshot of my Firestore DB to get some of my idea for the application:
[image]

If there is a way or a workaround on this problem I am facing, please do drop your answers. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will only display the list for the current user who has that UID, and this is not allowed in creating a working compound index."?

Comment: @AlexMamo first, I will correct myself that it was called **composite** index not compound. Anyway, what I meant by that is when I proceed in creating the composite index using what the logcat recommends me, it only works properly for users that has a UID of **TNn7J...J33**. When other users who are registered voters in my app try to vote, they cannot see the candidate list because they have different UIDs

Comment: I'm so sorry, but this time I really have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: Is there a way that I can demonstrate my problem to you? Like live streaming or video recording? That way you can understand what is my problem

Comment: You should wait, maybe someone will understand that better than me.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand the problem here. Your screenshot shows that the `candidateFullName` field is a simple field with a string value. Why can't you define an index on that specific field? In fact, that should happen automatically. So maybe the better question is, what is the meaning of `whereEqualTo("Voters." + voterID, false)` in your code, given that the field you're querying doens't have that structure?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good day to you sir Frank! `whereEqualTo("Voters." + voterID, false)` means that I am checking if the map field named, **Voters** in the documents of **Candidates** has a subfield (if it is called a subfield) name equivalent to `voterID` that has a `boolean` value of `false`. I used a `.` notation to access the subfield that's why it looks like that. Without using a `.` notation, I can't access the subfield, therefore, candidates won't show up to my app's voters.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. I was reading your code as if it was a Realtime Database query. :) Any reason you can't maker `Voters` a normal array field, and use `array-contains`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

Comment: I don't know how to insert an array as a field that's why I only used map :( @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I switched my `Voters` as a normal array field with a `String` field containing the current user's UID. But then my application crashed, and got this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.util.ArrayList (found in field 'Voters')`

Comment: Hi @HeroreH29, could you update your question with a code snippet to see what you tried and where is the current issue? Thanks

Comment: Hi @FaridShumbar I have changed my code since this issue, and I cannot provide any code snippet that you requested. I am forced to change my code because this school project is almost due since the time I posted this question and no one seems to understand my issue :(